# Get full URL from a CRM 2011 Document Location that has a relative URL

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm creating a CRM 2011 workflow that creates folders in Sharepoint.  My workflow creates Document Locations, all of which have a Parent Site and a Relative URL.  However, later in the workflow I need the overall URL from one of the Document Location.  All I can access is its relative URL and the name of its parent location (not its URL).

Is the only way to get this functionality through custom code or is there a simple fix in CRM I am missing?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to traverse the structure with custom code. 
That means you have to start from the location going all the way up until you find the parent.

I don't know any other way to get the absolute path.

Comment: I ended up writing the custom code and it works.  I used this class in order to get the full URL: [RetrieveAbsoluteAndSiteCollectionUrlRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrieveabsoluteandsitecollectionurlrequest.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)